# Restrict JS Counter to Two Number Decimals

Tags: javascript, counter, parseint

I have a JS counter which is working perfectly, but I want to restrict it to two numbers after the decimal point. Right now it can go as high as 9. Any ideas for solutions which won't mess up the rest of the code?

Here's a JSFiddle with my code, also listed below: https://jsfiddle.net/nd252525/26pvd7g3/3/

```
var INTERVAL_FIRST = 1;
var INCREMENT_FIRST = 0.86;
var START_VALUE_FIRST = 12574343;
var COUNT_FIRST = 0;

window.onload = function () {
  var msInterval2 = INTERVAL_FIRST * 1000;
  var NOW_FIRST = new Date();
  COUNT_FIRST =
    parseInt((NOW_FIRST - START_DATE) / msInterval2) * INCREMENT_FIRST +
    START_VALUE_FIRST;
  document.getElementById("first-ticker").innerHTML = addCommas(COUNT_FIRST);
  setInterval(
    "COUNT_FIRST += INCREMENT_FIRST; document.getElementById('first-ticker').innerHTML = addCommas(COUNT_FIRST);",
    msInterval2
  );
};

function addCommas(nStr) {
  nStr += "";
  x = nStr.split(".");
  x1 = x[0];
  x2 = x.length > 1 ? "." + x[1] : "";
  var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
  while (rgx.test(x1)) {
    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, "$1" + "," + "$2");
  }
  return x1 + x2;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Just a pointer. In JavaScript, we usually restrict the use of CAPITAL_CASE to variables that are constant (ie, that you aren't ever going to reassign).

Comment: @BenWainwright thanks for the tip! I don't work with JavaScript very often so always appreciate some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the [.toFixed(2)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method to your `COUNT_FIRST` variable to restrict it to 2 digits after the decimal point.

Your code will look like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var msInterval2 = INTERVAL_FIRST * 1000;
  var NOW_FIRST = new Date();
  COUNT_FIRST =
    parseInt((NOW_FIRST - START_DATE) / msInterval2) * INCREMENT_FIRST +
    START_VALUE_FIRST;
  
  // Add one here
  document.getElementById("first-ticker").innerHTML = addCommas(COUNT_FIRST.toFixed(2));

  // And one more here
  setInterval(
    "COUNT_FIRST += INCREMENT_FIRST; document.getElementById('first-ticker').innerHTML = addCommas(COUNT_FIRST.toFixed(2));",
    msInterval2
  );
};
```

The code was tested with your provided JSFiddle.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! Here's the link to the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nd252525/5h8pes2z/2/